# Sorting XML having xsd format using xslt

Tags: xslt, xsd

Sort XML with xsd format in ascending order

Because of xsd format in XML my xslt solution was not working ,what must be used in case of xsd?

Here is my XML Input:

4
        
        
            1
        
        
            7
        
    
 
What I tried:

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/*">
xsl:copy
xsl:apply-templates
<xsl:sort select="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>
What i expect as Output:

1
        
        
            4
        
        
            7

Comment: Sort XML with xsd format in ascending order

Because of xsd format in XML my xslt solution was not working ,what must be used in case of xsd?

Here is my XML Input:

<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns="tempuri.org/Test.xsd">
    <customer>
        <number>
            4
        </number>
        <number>
            1
        </number>
        <number>
            7
        </number>
    </customer>
</test>

Comment: What I tried:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: What i expect as Output:

<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns="tempuri.org/Test.xsd">
    <customer>
        <number>
            1
        </number>
        <number>
            4
        </number>
        <number>
            7
        </number>
    </customer>
</test>

Comment: Don't add information as comments please. Edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something close to this (leaving out the namespace and other declarations around):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="test">
    <xsl:for-each select="//number">
      <xsl:sort select="text(.)" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This din't work

Comment: Sorry, as I said: I left out declaration etc. Here is the complete stylesheet: 
```<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:test="tempuri.org/Test.xsd">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="test">
   <xsl:for-each select="//test:number">
    <xsl:sort select="text()" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>```